# Writing a Modified Image to Disk

Tags: c#, encryption, io

I have an image on my drive, I encrypted the bytes by adding a numerical value, now how can I write that modified file and replace the old one?

Here's my encryption method [very newbish because I'm just getting a feel for things :P ]:

```
    private void EncryptFile()
    {            
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";
        dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop";
        dialog.Title = "Please select an image file to encrypt.";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            byte[] ImageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dialog.FileName);

            for (int i = 0; i < ImageBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                ImageBytes[i] = (byte)(ImageBytes[i] + 5);
            }                
        }             
    }
```

I'm stuck there. I don't really know how to procede. Technically, after that for loop, I have my modifed image inside of the byte[] ImageBytes. Now how can I write it in the exact same location as the image?

**Woah! On a side note, am I reading the file correctly by using dialog.FileName. Does that return the file's path?**

Comment: What's the point of doing a Caesar cipher? That's trivial to break. :-P

Comment: LEARNING DAMN YOU! LEARNING! xD No, but really just as a step to using XOR or some other harder cypher. Just learning things really. Never done something like this. :D Plus, I just finished playing Assassin's Creed 2 and I want to feel like Leonardo.

Comment: XOR is a "harder" cipher? Seriously?! :-P Here I was thinking you might be considering implementing AES, and then people would just tell you to use what's built into the .NET Framework. Really, that's the only way to go unless you're a crypto expert. :-P

Comment: @Papuccino1: whoever told you that XOR is more difficult is fooling with you. And, BTW, please don't use the title field for the first sentence of your question. Please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllBytes(dialog.FileName, ImageBytes);
```